# Optimization - How to get total response time of SP page

Tags: performance, optimization, dashboard

I have some code tweaks that I believe will improve the performance of my pages. However, I'm not sure how to use the tools I have to get a total response time of my page (before and then after my code change to compare).

I have Firebug, Developer dashboard and Fiddler 2 installed. As far as I can see, they only show response times for each HTTP request. How would I get the total response time of the page I'm testing in either of these tools?

Comment: did you try the perf counters? http://sharepointgadget.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/performance-counters-sharepoint/

Comment: Use System Center Operations Manager for monitoring SharePoint or a 3rd party tool like Quest Foglight for ASP. Foglight can capture trends like page load times as well as consolidate performance counters.

Comment: IE 11 has a nice UI Responsiveness section that will give you all sorts of analytics including total page load time.

Comment: All awesome suggestions. I'll give each of them a try thanks dudes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug displays the total response time of a page incl. the time when the `onload` event was fired within the summary row at the bottom of the network requests inside its [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel).

[image: Total response time within Firebug]